Как мигрировать с angularjs на vue3 помодульно?
Есть проект в котором клиентская часть написана с применением angularjs. Хочу переписать на vue, проблема в том что проект довольно большой и переписать все сразу не представляется возможным, поэтому прошу подсказать алгоритм действий по переносу "небольшими модулями".
P.S.: я это представляю как то так: в проект подключаю vue, реализую необходимый модуль, подключаю необходимый модуль в index.html. но предполагаю что будут сложности, поэтому прошу подсказать чуть более подробно про то как сделать это наиболее грамотно

Сейчас как раз таким занимаемся, и я считаю, что это было ошибкой. Если бы можно было начать заново, то начал бы с чистого вью проекта и переписывал бы его "с нуля". У приложений на ангуляре и вью слишком разная архитетура, чтобы можно было помодульно переписывать.

под модулем я подразумеваю controller и связанный с ним сервис для работы с api, попробую, посмотрю как пойдет, но переписать все с нуля на текущий момент не представляется возможным

Попробовать однозначно хорошая идея, чтоб понимать самому, подходит вам такое или нет. Главное вовремя остановиться, если становится понятно, что такой подход работает не очень :) Удачи
